# Microsoft Security Advisory 4021279 System.BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

My application is an `ASP.NET Core 1.0 Web API`.

According to the [Microsoft Security Advisory 4021279](https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/12), I wanted to update the direct dependicies of my project.

In the `MyClassName.csproj` is the following line:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.0.3" />
```

which I change to:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.0.4" />
```

because the versions `1.0.0`, `1.0.1`, `1.0.2`, `1.0.3`
`1.1.0`, `1.1.1`, `1.1.2` of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` are not save to use.

If I then try to run the project, Iam getting the following errormessage:

> System.BadImageFormatException: "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058)"
>
> Inner Exception: BadImageFormatException: Cannot load a reference assembly for execution.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So [The post on Git](https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/12) says the following:

> If after recompilation you see a Dependency conflict warning, you must update your other direct dependencies to the appropriate version.
>
> For example if your project refers to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing with a version number of 1.0.1 when you update your Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc package to 1.0.4, compilation will throw:
>
> NU1012 Dependency conflict. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core 1.0.4 expected Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing >= 1.0.4 but received 1.0.1

As you can see in my question, I do not get this error message. However, I updated the version of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing` to `1.0.4` and everything worked.